# SQL - Left Join according to Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**Facts**

> 1. There are two tables MachineStatus and MachineShift.
> 2. They are linking to each other by FK: machineName.

**Output Required**

> TO get Machine Status Duration according to shifts
>   Please find attached image to clarify the output.

[image]

**Problem**

I am unable to achieve old dates status, what will be a condition to meet the criteria in Left Join?
*Any help will be appreciated*

**DB schema**

```
DECLARE @machineStatus  TABLE  (id int, DateFrom DATETIME, DateTo DATETIME, mStatus int, machineName Varchar(10));

INSERT INTO @machineStatus
(id, dateFrom, DateTo, mStatus, machineName)
VALUES
    (1, '2017-01-24 08:00', '2017-01-24 09:00', 1, 'MachineA'),
    (2, '2017-01-24 09:00', '2017-01-24 09:30', 2, 'MachineA'),
    (3, '2017-01-24 09:30', '2017-01-24 18:30', 1, 'MachineA'),
    (4, '2017-01-24 18:30', '2017-01-24 21:30', 2, 'MachineA'),
    (5, '2017-01-24 21:30', '2017-01-25 00:30', 3, 'MachineA')
    ,(6, '2017-01-25 00:30', NULL, 1, 'MachineA')
    ;

--SELECT * FROM @machineStatus

DECLARE @machineShift TABLE 
    (id int, TimeStart TIME, TimeEnd TIME, MachineName varchar(10), machineShift int);

INSERT INTO @machineShift
(id, TimeStart, TimeEnd, MachineName, machineShift)
VALUES
    (1, '08:30', '20:30', 'MachineA', 1),
    (2, '20:30', '08:30', 'MachineA', 2),
    (3, '09:30', '21:00', 'MachineB', 1),
    (4, '21:00', '08:30', 'MachineB', 2)
    ;

--SELECT * FROM @machineShift
```

**Query**

```
SELECT ms.id, ms.DateFrom, ms.DateTo, ms.mStatus, sft.machineName,
        sft.machineShift,
        DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', CAST(ms.DateFrom AS DATE)), CAST (sft.TimeStart AS DATETIME)
        ) AS ShiftStart,

        DATEADD(DAY, 
            CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, CAST(sft.TimeStart AS TIME), CAST(sft.TimeEnd AS TIME)) <= 0  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
            DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', CAST(ms.DateFrom AS DATE)), CAST(sft.TimeEnd AS DATETIME))
        ) AS ShiftEnd

FROM            @machineStatus AS ms 
LEFT JOIN       @machineShift    AS sft 
                    ON (ms.machineName = sft.machineName
                    AND  ms.DateFrom >=  
                         DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', CAST(ms.DateFrom AS DATE)), CAST(sft.TimeStart AS DATETIME)) 
                    AND ms.DateFrom <= DATEADD(DAY, 
                                       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, CAST(sft.TimeStart AS TIME), CAST(sft.TimeEnd AS TIME)) <= 0  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
                                       DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', CAST(ms.DateFrom AS DATE)), CAST(sft.TimeEnd AS DATETIME)))  
                    )
```